# Using MSHTML in VB.Net to parse HTML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mshtml

Was wondering if someone could give me some direction on this. I've spent a decent amount of time on it and don't seem to be getting anywhere:

I have a hidden field that I'm trying to parse out of an HTML document in VB.Net. I'm using a System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control in a WPF application and handling the LoadCompleted event. Inside the LoadCompleted event handler I do something like this:

```
Dim htmlDocument As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = Me.WebBrowser.Document
Dim allElements As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = htmlDocument.body.all
Dim hiddenField As mshtml.IHTMLInputElement = allElements.tags("hidField")
```

The hidden field that I'm trying to access is declared in my .aspx file as such:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidField"/>
```

The problem is that this `allElements.tags("hidField")` is returning null. Am I doing something wrong with the mshtml library? I don't have much experience with it and gathered that I needed to do something like this to find my hidden field element. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's is my final working solution for anyone interested:

```
    Dim htmlDocument As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = Me.WebBrowser.Document
    Dim allElements As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = htmlDocument.body.all
    Dim allInputs As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection = allElements.tags("input")

    For Each element As mshtml.IHTMLInputElement In allInputs
        If element.type = "hidden" And element.name.Contains("hidField") Then
            MessageBox.Show(element.value)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for the rendered tag, not the serverside value.

This will be rendered as an `<input type="hidden">`, so you need to use `allElements.tags("input")`, then find the specific hidden one. The `id` attribute may not end up as `hidField` - it depends on what container controls it is in and in what nesting level.

I suggest using the [HTML Agilty Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and find the element instead - it should be easier to use than MSHTML.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I did what you suggested and ended up getting an exception on that line which I'm guess is something that I'm not doing right with MSHTML: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'mshtml.IHTMLInputElement'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3050F5D2-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: I may give the HTML Agility Pack a try.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I used MSHTML, but if I remember correctly you need to use something like
`htmlDocument.getElementById('hidField')`

Comment: Hmmm...I was seeing that method suggested elsewhere also but it is not available on the mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 object.